# How to use S3 server-side encryption with fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm currently trying to find a solution to enable S3 server side encryption for my uploads.

Using fine-uploader-4.1.1

Referencing the fine-uploader docs, it seemed like I could just pass the "x-amz-server-side-encryption" header with the customHeaders option, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Could anyone provide the proper way to request server side encryption on an object? I would also be satisfied with a global bucket-wide encryption option if that exists, but I don't think it does.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently Fine Uploader does not have support for appending `"x-amz-server-side-encryption"` to upload request headers. I'd open up a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've added it to the issue tracker.